# Does this series diverge? If so, any ideas on how to prove it?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I suspect that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\cos(2\pi n/3)}{\ln(1+n)}\right)^3$$
diverges, but having used all the criterion for divergence I can think of, I haven't come up with anything yet. Note that for $n=1,2$ the numerator is $-1/8$, and for $n=3$ it is 1. I suspect it diverges because we don't even have the conditions to apply the Dirichlet criterion, since the partial sums of $\cos(2\pi n/3)$ are not bounded.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It is quasi-alternating.... $n \equiv 0\pmod 3$ the sign of $a_n$ is positive and  $a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}$ are negative.  If you can show that $|a_n| < |a_{n+1} + a_{n+2}| < |a_{n+3}|$ then the series is conditionally convergent.

Comment: estimate the sum for $n=4,5,6$ by writing out the three terms

Comment: then do $n=7,8,9$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the series diverges. Notice that $\frac1{\ln(1+3n)^3},\frac1{\ln(1+3n+1)^3},\frac1{\ln(1+3n+2)^3}\sim\frac1{\ln(n)^3}$ are the terms of diverging series by Bertrand's criterion. Setting $S_n=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{\ln(k)^3}$ we have $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\ln(1+3k)^3}, \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\ln(1+3k+1)^3}, \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\ln(1+3k+2)^3}\sim S_n$ and so
$$\sum_{k=1}^{3n}\left(\frac{\cos(2\pi k/3)}{\ln(1+k)}\right)^3=S_n-\frac28S_n+o(S_n)=\frac34S_n+o(S_n)$$
which diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: @ClementC. Right! Fixed it.

Comment: Excellent, answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't pass the divergence test.  Use L'hopital on the general term:  $|\dfrac{-2\pi/3\sin(2\pi k/3)}{1/(1+k)}|\to\infty$.