Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^3$ for $a_n = \cos(2nπ/3)/ln(1+ n)$
In "Problems in Real Analysis; Advanced Calculus on the Real Axis" it is stated that for $a_n = \dfrac{\cos(2nπ/3)}{ln(1+ n)}$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is converge but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^3$ diverges. What test or properties we can use to show it?

For the divergence of $\sum a_n^3$ see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3949088/42969

$c_n = \frac{1}{ln(1+n)}$ is monotonic with $\lim_{n\to 
\infty} c_n = 0$.
Let $b_n = \cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3})$. Then $|\sum_{n = 0}^N b_n|$ is bounded (see this, for example).
$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_n b_n$ converges by Dirichlet.

Use the identity:
$$\cos^3(x)=\frac{3\cos(x)+\cos(3x)}{4},$$
then
$$\cos^3(2nπ/3)=\frac{1+3\cos(2nπ/3)}{4}.$$
The series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4\ln^3(1+n)}$$
diverges and
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3\cos(2nπ/3)}{4\ln^3(1+n)}$$
converges.
This implies $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{\cos(2nπ/3)}{ln(1+ n)}\right)^3$$
diverges.
